# Adding basic auth to node.js + express has no effect

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication

I have added the following

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require("fs");

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
var basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'worker': '????????' }
}));
```

to my `app.js`. Depending on place, where I put this code, the site either stops work at all (displaying white space) or works without any auth.

Which is the correct place to put this code?

When white space, in Chrome Developer tools can be seen

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

but no login popup appears.

I am running my site on `localhost` under WebStorm. May be no popups is default browser behavior on `localhost`? Firefox does the same

Answer (score 1):

With [basic-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth), I use following code (in app.js or if you want this only on certain routes, then before those routes only):

```
var auth = require('basic-auth');

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var user = auth(req);

    if (user === undefined || user['name'] !== 'mike' || user['pass'] !== 'mike123') {
        res.statusCode = 401;
        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="NodeJS"');
        res.end('Unauthorized');
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By using **express-basic-auth** module, default configuration of the middleware does not add a `WWW-Authenticate` challenge header to responses of unauthorized requests. You must enable it by adding `challenge: true` to the options object as follows:

```
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'worker': '????????' },
    challenge: true
}));
```

This piece of code will allow most browsers to show a popup to enter username/password on unauthorized responses.